# SQL query that uses result in itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I am running a simple query like

```
DECLARE @find varchar(60) = 'findme';

SELECT *
FROM Queue
WHERE 
    column1 LIKE '%' + @find + '%' OR
    column2 LIKE '%' + @find + '%' OR
    column3 LIKE '%' + @find + '%' OR
    ....
```

This just tells me every entry where the 'findme' string is in any column.
Problem now is, in 'ColumnExtra' will always be a String that contains a Name of another table (Like extra Information can be found here) and "ColumnName" contains the ID of the current User.

I need to search the "ColumnName" table(for the given 'ColumnName' user) for 'findme' as well, and for every hit, no matter if only in original table or in "ColumnName" table or in both, i need all Information from both possible tables.

For example:

Original table

```
User             1         2         3
-----------------------------------------
Column1:      string1   string1   string3
Column2:      string1   string2   string3
Column3:      findme    string2   string3
ColumnExtra:  table1    table3    table4
ColumnName:   uid1      uid2      uid3
```

Table1 (for user 1)

```
C1:    asdfg
C2:    qwert
```

Table3 (for user 2)

```
D1:    poiu
D2:    trew
```

Table4 (for user 3)

```
E1:    aaaaaa
E2:    findme
```

The SQL query should return the following result:

```
User             1         3 
--------------------------------
Coulmn1:      string1   string3
Coulmn2:      string1   string3
Coulmn3:      findme    string3
CoulmnExtra:  table1    table4
CoulmnName:   uid1      uid3
C1:           asdfg
C2:           qwert
E1:                     aaaaa`enter code here`a
E2:                     findme
```

If it isnt possible like this, than the next best solution would be

```
User             1         3 
Column1:      string1   string3
Column2:      string1   string3
Column3:      findme    string3
ColumnExtra:  table1    table4
ColumnName:   uid1      uid3
C1:           asdfg     whateverishere
C2:           qwert     whateverishere
E1:           whatev    aaaaaa
E2:           whatev    findme
```

Comment: If possible, I would recommend that you completely redesign this table structure.  This is very poor design and these are the only the start of the problems you are going to have if you continue with it.

Comment: Thanks but that is not an Option and this kinf od querry s not used on daily Basis. it woul djust help me bug track a lot of stuff

Comment: If you can not redesign the table structure, you can use dynamic query

Comment: Do you have an example or a page wher ei can read up on it? I dont use SQL on a daily Basis.

Comment: It sounds like your data modelling has gone badly wrong somewhere, with lots of inappropriate mixing of data/metadata. All data of the same "type", such that you want to write comparison against all such data values ought to be in a *single* column.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

You have a problem with your data structure.  You can get around this by creating a view of *all* tables that might be referenced:

```
create view all_referenced_tables as
    select 'table1' as table_name, c1 as col1, c2 as col2 from table1 union all
    select 'table2', d1, d2 from table2 union all
    select 'table3', e1, e2 from table3;
```

Then, you can use this in your query:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM Queue q LEFT JOIN
     all_referenced_tables art
     ON q.column_extra = art.table_name
WHERE q.column1 LIKE '%' + @find + '%' OR
      q.column2 LIKE '%' + @find + '%' OR
      q.column3 LIKE '%' + @find + '%' OR
      art.column1 LIKE '%' + @find + '%' OR
      art.column2 LIKE '%' + @find + '%'
```